# Verbs for phlegm?

Tags: word-request, verbs

What are verbs for phlegm? For example, what is the verb to describe the action of blowing out  the phlegm from throat? Or the verb to describe someone has or generates phlegm in one's throat?

Comment: Thank you all very much and suggestion! The verb for projecting phlegm onto ground or someone's face is to spit. In fact it is still my original question. I am looking for plural verbs for phlegm, and cough up is one example. I edited it.

Comment: ***Ahem!*** This is a good question! :)

Comment: a verb does not describe.  a verb *does*.

Comment: ？I dont get it.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the verbs above, there's also "[hawk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hawk)" which can be used, although it might fall under the remit of 'slang'

> **hawk** (hôk)
>
> 1. To clear or attempt to clear the throat by or as if by coughing up phlegm.
> 2. To clear the throat of (phlegm).
> 3. An audible effort to clear the throat by expelling phlegm.

Comment: I have never seen this word written before, but I hear it _all the time (!)_ .  Many people pronounce it as if it were spelled _hack._  I don't know if they are different words, or different pronunciations, or what the distinction even means in a word that is so much more common in spoken English than written English.   Also frequently used to describe how cats disengorge hairballs.

Comment: @Adam I definitely think it's slang, but in my experience, hack and hawk are different words.  If you're coughing a lot, you're "hacking up a lung".  If you're doing something similar to clearing your throat to produce something that you can spit out, you're "hawking a loogie".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Would you say that a cat _hacks_ up a hairball or _hawks_ up a hairball?

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure whether I'd use either for a cat with a hairball, but if I had to choose, probably "hawk", since it's producing something that comes out.  "Hacking up a lung", despite "up" suggesting that something is produced, doesn't have as much suggestion (to me) that something is coming out.

Comment: @Joshua: Quite. OED specifically defines a ***hacking cough*** as *a short, **dry,** frequently repeated cough*, where ***dry*** strongly implies "non-expectorant" (i.e. - no mucus is brought up). On the other hand, they define the relevant sense of the verb ***hawk*** as *To make an effort **to clear the throat of phlegm;** to clear the throat noisily.* So I absolutely agree your point about ***hawk*** "suggesting that something is produced".

Comment: Thanks guys - Nothing like refining one's vocabulary for bodily functions.  I am totally ready to be middle-aged now.

Answer (score 6):

As James Webster said, **coughs up** could be used:

> Force (something, especially blood) out of the lungs or throat by coughing

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cough?q=cough+up#cough__9

You can also use the verb **expectorate**:

> Cough or spit out (phlegm) from the throat or lungs

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expectorate

Comment: +1 for 'expectorate'. I remember my old days when we used to classify cough sirups - anti-tussive, ***expectorant***, mucolytic and all! :)

Answer (score 2):

One usually "[coughs up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cough+up)" phlegm.

> v.intr To expel air from the lungs suddenly and noisily, often to keep the respiratory passages free of irritating material.
>
> v.tr.
> To expel by coughing

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, "cough up" is a standard term now.
For an older or more formal term, you might try:

[expectorate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expectorate)